# Excel VBA Global variable

Tags: vba, excel

Can variable declared in the Private Sub Workbook_Open of the ThisWorkbook Excel Object be accessed by another method in another module? I want to declare and assign a variable at the start of my code that can be changed by any module using it. This change should be reflected in the variable when the next method calls it.

I have a sub in a module that assigns value to the public variable.
I require this value set by module1 to be accessible to that of module2

Comment: A variable that's declared in a procedure scope can't be global, it's *local* to that procedure. Read up on scoping, and also learn how to pass parameters between procedures. 99% of what you do with a global variable can be done with parameters instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on the answer of @David, this is how to use Dim and Public and their differences (in a Modul, named `Modul1` write the following and run `TestMe`):

```
Dim a           As String
Public b        As String
Private c       As String
Global d        As String

Private Sub TestA()
'Whatever is not declared in TestMe, would take its value from here for the print.
'^-If it is declared, the value would be attached to the public/private/dim/glb above.    
    a = 11
    b = 22
    c = 33
    d = 44        
End Sub

Private Sub TestMe()

    Dim a       As String
    'Dim b       As String
    'Dim c       As String
    Dim d       As String

    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4

    TestA

    Debug.Print a; vbTab; Modul1.a
    Debug.Print "----------------"
    Debug.Print b; vbTab; Modul1.b
    Debug.Print "----------------"
    Debug.Print c; vbTab; Modul1.c
    Debug.Print "----------------"
    Debug.Print d; vbTab; Modul1.d

End Sub
```

This is what you get:

```
1    11
----------------
22    22
----------------
33    33
----------------
4    44
```

Answer (score 10):

A *global variable* needs to have `Public` accessibility, and be declared at *module-scope* in a *standard module* (.bas).

```
Option Explicit
Public Foo As Long ' global variable
```

The problem with global variables is that they can be *read **and** written to* by anything anywhere in the code: global state easily leads to unmaintainable spaghetti code and should be avoided whenever possible.

There are a number of alternatives, notably using **parameters**:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SomeEntryPoint()
    Dim foo As Long ' local variable
    DoSomething foo
    MsgBox foo 'prints 42
End Sub

'this procedure could be in any module, public.
Private Sub DoSomething(ByRef foo As Long)
    foo = 42 'byref assignment; caller will receive the updated value
End Sub
```

Another alternative, if the variable needs to be **written** by the module that declares it, but needs to be **read** from somewhere else, is to use **properties**:

```
Option Explicit
Private foo As Long ' private field

Public Sub DoSomething()
    'do stuff...
    foo = 42
    '...
End Sub

Public Property Get SomeFoo() As Long
    SomeFoo = foo
End Property
```

Now code in *that* module can *write* to `foo` as needed, and other modules can only *read* `foo` through the `SomeFoo` property - assuming the field and property are defined in `Module1`:

```
Debug.Print Module1.SomeFoo 'gets the value of the encapsulated private field
```

Answer (score 2):

No - the variable should be declared as Public in a normal module.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Public variable
Public a as String

' Local variable
Public sub hello()
    Dim a as String
End sub
```

The first `a` is public and you can use where you want and the second variable is local and the only site you can use is into the function `hello()`. So both variable are diferent.

Comment: `Dim` is never public. This answer is wrong and misleading. That "private variable" is really a *local* variable, and what you're calling a "public variable" is in fact a *private field*, a module-scope variable that can only be accessed within that module.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for comment, you have right. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be called out, as you are calling a Private Sub.

In order to have variables which can be changed Publically, try outside of any Sub:

```
Public wBk As Workbook 
Public var As String
```

This would declare the variables. To modify the values, you need to set them in a public Subroutine:

```
Public Sub myPublicVar()
Set wBk = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm")
Set var = "Whatever you like"
End Sub
```

If then you want your module, or subroutine to include the variables, you would do the following

```
Sub myOtherSub()
Call myPublicVar
MsgBox var
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Public var1 as String
    
    Sub M1()
    var1 = "Excel"
    End Sub

    Sub M2()
    MsgBox var
    End Sub

Comment: Ok, so: `Public var1 as String` - Makes var1 a public string Instead of `Sub M1()`, use  `Public Sub M1()` As this will let you use the variable in another sub. In your third Sub you need to do the following: `Sub M2(), call M1, MsgBox var1, End Sub`