# Calling a variable from outside module (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a clever way of storing variables globally so that you can call them at any of the modules at anytime?

Example

```
Dim pwd As String
pwd = "password"

Private Sub Test()
    MsgBox (pwd)
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a constant.

```
Public Const pwd as String = "password"
```

Declare it on top of a standard module.

For other solutions with subs, functions or properties look at the Related-Section on the right side of the page.

Comment: I intend to manipulate it in one or more of the functions in the module. Is constant viable?

Comment: @OdaySalim a constant is constant ;) Not changeable! I would suggest a property. See answer of [Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772270/excel-vba-global-variable/46772922#46772922)  and have a look at the other related questions as I told you.

Answer (score 0):

> Global pwd As String

inside of a module-level module (not a sheet-level module).