# Excel UserForm to Search and Update Existing records

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have this Excel Userform which allows you to Add, View Next/Previous & First/Last records and also Search records within the Userform.

I am having issues saving records after searching and updating a specific record.

The UserForm has the following VBA code below.

```
    Private Sub btnClose_Click()
        Me.Hide
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFirst_Click()
        FirstRecord
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnLast_Click()
        Last Record
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnNew_Click()
        NewRecord
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnNext_Click()
        NextRecord
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click()
        PreviousRecord
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSaveRecord_Click()
        SaveRecord (RowNumber)
    End Sub


    'Private Sub cmdUpdateRec_Click()
    '    EditRecord (RowNumber)
    'End Sub

    Private Sub SearchMemberID_Click()
        SearchMemID
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchMember_Click()
        SearchMem
    End Sub


    Private Sub userform_initialize()

     Dim strShtNameMenu As String

     strShtNameMenu = "Menu Options"

     Me.CBxCompUpheld.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Complaint_Upheld").Value
     Me.CBxIssueResolved.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Issue_Resolved").Value
     Me.CBxMemberSatisfied.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Member_Satisfied").Value
     Me.CBxCompAgainst.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Complaint_Against").Value
     Me.CBxDept.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Department").Value
     'Me.CBxOwner.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Owner").Value
     Me.CBxMember.List = Sheets(strShtNameMenu).Range("Member").Value

     ShowRecord (3)

    End Sub
```

These CommandButtons are calling macros from a module which is below.

```
    Public shtNameLog As String
    Public shtNameMenu As String
    Public frmNameComplaints As String
    Public RowNumber As Integer 'current row
    'Dim RowNumber As Long
    Public intLastRow As Integer 'last row
    Public RecordRefNmbr As Integer
    Dim strSrch As String

    '''' First Record ''''

    Sub FirstRecord()
    Dim RecordRefNmbr
    RecordRefNmbr = 3
    ShowRecord (RecordRefNmbr)
    End Sub

    '''' Last Record ''''

    Sub LastRecord()
    Dim RecordRefNmbr
    Sheets("Log").Select
    RecordRefNmbr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ShowRecord (RecordRefNmbr)
    End Sub

    '''' New Record ''''

    Sub NewRecord()
    Sheets("Log").Select
    intLastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ShowRecord (intLastRow + 1)
    End Sub

    '''' Next Record ''''

    Sub NextRecord()
    Sheet1.Select
    intLastRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If RowNumber = intLastRow Then
       MsgBox "This is the last complaint record.", vbOKOnly, "Last Record reached"
    Else
       ShowRecord (RowNumber + 1)
    End If
    End Sub

    '''' Previous Record ''''

    Sub PreviousRecord()
    If RowNumber = 3 Then
        ShowRecord (RowNumber)
        MsgBox "This is the first complaint record.", vbOKOnly, "First Record reached"
    Else
        ShowRecord (RowNumber - 1)
    End If
    End Sub

    '''' Membership ID Search ''''

    Sub SearchMemID()

    Dim TBrow As Long
    Dim BV As String ', strSrch As String
    Dim RecordNmbr              As Integer
    Dim strFormName             As String
    '    Dim txtDateRaised           As Date 'String
    '    Dim txtMemberID             As String
    '    Dim txtName                 As String
    '    Dim txtCompAgainst          As String
    '    Dim txtCompCategory         As String
    '    Dim txtDept                 As String
    '    Dim txtInitialAdvisor       As String
    '    Dim txtOwner                As String
    '    Dim txtBriefDesc            As String
    '    Dim txtFindings             As String
    '    Dim txtOutcome              As String
    '    Dim txtActions              As String
    '    Dim txtComplaintUpheld      As String
    '    Dim txtFollowUpDate         As Date 'String
    '    Dim txtIssueResolved        As String
    '    Dim txtMemberSatisfied      As String
    '    Dim txtDateClosed           As Date 'String

    shtNameLog = "Log"
    strFormName = "frmNameComplaints"
    'RecordNmbr = RecordRefNmbr
    'RecordRefNmbr = RecordNmbr
    RowNumber = RecordNmbr

    strSrch = ComplaintsLog.TextBox2.Value
    Set TB = Sheets(shtNameLog).Range("D:D").Find(what:=strSrch, lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not TB Is Nothing Then

    RecordNmbr = TB.Row

    With ComplaintsLog

    .txtDateRaised.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value
    .CBxMember.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 3).Value
    .txtMemberID.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 4).Value
    .txtName.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 5).Value
    .CBxCompAgainst.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 6).Value
    .txtCompCategory.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 7).Value
    .CBxDept.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 8).Value
    .txtInitialAdvisor.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 11).Value
    .txtOwner.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 12).Value
    .txtBriefDesc.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 9).Value
    .txtFindings.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 10).Value
    .txtOutcome.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 16).Value
    .txtActions.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 17).Value
    .CBxCompUpheld.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 13).Value
    .txtFollowUpDate.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 14).Value
    .CBxIssueResolved.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 15).Value
    .CBxMemberSatisfied.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 18).Value
    .txtDateClosed.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 19).Value

    End With

      Else
    MsgBox "Error, Value Not Found!"
    End
    End If

     BV = Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value

    End Sub

    '''' Customer/ Member Search ''''

    Sub SearchMem()

    'Dim TB As Range
    Dim TBrow As Long
    Dim BV As String ', strSrch As String
    Dim strFormName             As String
    '    Dim txtDateRaised           As Date 'String
    '    Dim txtMemberID             As String
    '    Dim txtName                 As String
    '    Dim txtCompAgainst          As String
    '    Dim txtCompCategory         As String
    '    Dim txtDept                 As String
    '    Dim txtInitialAdvisor       As String
    '    Dim txtOwner                As String
    '    Dim txtBriefDesc            As String
    '    Dim txtFindings             As String
    '    Dim txtOutcome              As String
    '    Dim txtActions              As String
    '    Dim txtComplaintUpheld      As String
    '    Dim txtFollowUpDate         As Date 'String
    '    Dim txtIssueResolved        As String
    '    Dim txtMemberSatisfied      As String
    '    Dim txtDateClosed           As Date 'String
    Dim RecordNmbr As Integer

    shtNameLog = "Log"
    strFormName = "frmNameComplaints"
    RecordNmbr = RecordRefNmbr
    RowNumber = RecordNmbr

    strSrch = ComplaintsLog.TextBox1.Value
    Set TB = Sheets(shtNameLog).Range("E:E").Find(what:=strSrch, lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not TB Is Nothing Then

    RecordNmbr = TB.Row

    With ComplaintsLog

    .txtDateRaised.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value
    .CBxMember.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 3).Value
    .txtMemberID.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 4).Value
    .txtName.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 5).Value
    .CBxCompAgainst.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 6).Value
    .txtCompCategory.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 7).Value
    .CBxDept.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 8).Value
    .txtInitialAdvisor.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 11).Value
    .txtOwner.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 12).Value
    .txtBriefDesc.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 9).Value
    .txtFindings.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 10).Value
    .txtOutcome.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 16).Value
    .txtActions.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 17).Value
    .CBxCompUpheld.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 13).Value
    .txtFollowUpDate.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 14).Value
    .CBxIssueResolved.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 15).Value
    .CBxMemberSatisfied.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 18).Value
    .txtDateClosed.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 19).Value

    End With

    Else
       MsgBox "Error, Value Not Found!"
    End
    End If

    BV = Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value

    End Sub

    '''' Show Record ''''

    Sub ShowRecord(RecordRefNmbr)

    Dim RecordNmbr              As Integer
    Dim strFormName             As String
    Dim txtDateRaised           As Date 'String
    Dim txtMemberID             As String
    Dim txtName                 As String
    Dim txtCompAgainst          As String
    Dim txtCompCategory         As String
    Dim txtDept                 As String
    Dim txtInitialAdvisor       As String
    Dim txtOwner                As String
    Dim txtBriefDesc            As String
    Dim txtFindings             As String
    Dim txtOutcome              As String
    Dim txtActions              As String
    Dim txtComplaintUpheld      As String
    Dim txtFollowUpDate         As Date 'String
    Dim txtIssueResolved        As String
    Dim txtMemberSatisfied      As String
    Dim txtDateClosed           As Date 'String

    shtNameLog = "Log"
    strFormName = "frmNameComplaints"
    RecordNmbr = RecordRefNmbr
    RowNumber = RecordNmbr
    With ComplaintsLog

        .txtDateRaised.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value
        .CBxMember.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 3).Value
        .txtMemberID.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 4).Value
        .txtName.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 5).Value
        .CBxCompAgainst.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 6).Value
        .txtCompCategory.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 7).Value
        .CBxDept.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 8).Value
        .txtInitialAdvisor.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 11).Value
        .txtOwner.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 12).Value
        .txtBriefDesc.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 9).Value
        .txtFindings.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 10).Value
        .txtOutcome.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 16).Value
        .txtActions.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 17).Value
        .CBxCompUpheld.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 13).Value
        .txtFollowUpDate.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 14).Value
        .CBxIssueResolved.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 15).Value
        .CBxMemberSatisfied.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 18).Value
        .txtDateClosed.Value = Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 19).Value

    End With
    End Sub

    '''' Save Record ''''

    Sub SaveRecord(RecordRefNmbr)
    '
    'Dim TBrow As Long
    'Dim BV As String, strSrch As String
    'Dim txtDateRaised           As Date 'String
    'Dim txtMemberID             As String
    'Dim txtName                 As String
    'Dim txtCompAgainst          As String
    'Dim txtCompCategory         As String
    'Dim txtDept                 As String
    'Dim txtInitialAdvisor       As String
    'Dim txtOwner                As String
    'Dim txtBriefDesc            As String
    'Dim txtFindings             As String
    'Dim txtOutcome              As String
    'Dim txtActions              As String
    'Dim txtComplaintUpheld      As String
    'Dim txtFollowUpDate         As Date 'String
    'Dim txtIssueResolved        As String
    'Dim txtMemberSatisfied      As String
    'Dim txtDateClosed           As Date 'String
    Dim shtNameLog As String
    Dim strFormName As String
    Dim RecordNmbr As Integer
    Dim RowNumber As String

    shtNameLog = "Log"
    strFormName = "frmNameComplaints"
    RecordNmbr = RecordRefNmbr
    'RowNumber = RecordNmbr
    'RowNumber = RecordRefNmbr

    With ComplaintsLog
        If Not IsDate(.txtDateRaised.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Date Raised must be entered in format 'DD/MM/YYYY' "
    Else
    Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value = DateValue(Format(.txtDateRaised.Value,            
    "DD/MM/YYYY"))
        End If
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 3).Value = .CBxMember.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 4).Value = .txtMemberID.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 5).Value = .txtName.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 6).Value = .CBxCompAgainst.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 7).Value = .txtCompCategory.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 8).Value = .CBxDept.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 11).Value = .txtInitialAdvisor.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 12).Value = .txtOwner.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 9).Value = Replace(.txtBriefDesc.Value, Chr(10), " ")
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 10).Value = Replace(.txtFindings.Value, Chr(10), " ")
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 16).Value = Replace(.txtOutcome.Value, Chr(10), " ")
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 17).Value = Replace(.txtActions.Value, Chr(10), " ")
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 13).Value = .CBxCompUpheld.Value
        If .txtFollowUpDate.Value = "" Then
            Else
                If Not IsDate(.txtFollowUpDate.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Follow Up Date must be entered in format 'DD/MM/YYYY' "
            Else
                Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 14).Value = 
    DateValue(Format(.txtFollowUpDate.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY"))
                End If
        End If
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 15).Value = .CBxIssueResolved.Value
        Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 18).Value = .CBxMemberSatisfied.Value
        If .txtDateClosed.Value = "" Then
            Else
                If Not IsDate(.txtDateClosed.Text) Then
                    MsgBox "Date Closed must be entered in format 'DD/MM/YYYY' "
            Else
                Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 19).Value = 
     DateValue(Format(.txtDateClosed.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY"))
                End If
        End If
    End With
        MsgBox "Record Saved"
    End Sub
```

With the current coding, when I attempt to update a record which I've searched for, it errors with the message

> 'run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error'.

on the line

```
Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value = DateValue(Format(.txtDateRaised.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

I did inherit this file/code, so and I am a beginner at VBA so any help would be useful. If there is a different/simpler approach that I can take I am open to suggestions.

[Click on this link to see what the userform looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YljeM.png)

Comment: What line throws that error?

Comment: the line Sheets(shtNameLog).Cells(RecordNmbr, 2).Value = 
        DateValue(Format(.txtDateRaised.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")) in sub saverecord. It does not pass through the rownumber that's been picked up when searched.

Comment: All variables declared `As Integer` should be declared `As Long`. Then, what is the value of `RecordNmbr` when that fails? I'm assuming it's probably 0.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I've changed the variables as you've suggested. Also when it fails the value of 'RecordNmbr' is **0**

Comment: And that will fail, because Excel doesn't have a row 0. The `Public` variable setup could be / is problematic.

Comment: In which case, what variable would you suggest to overcome this? Dim?

Comment: It's not as simple as declaring a new variable. You'd need to refactor the existing code to some other schema than `Public` variables.

Comment: How would you go about doing this? Apologies - I am a beginner level with VBA...

Comment: It's kind of a broad topic, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772922/9245853) is a start.