# are all global variables in all modules in a spreadsheet declared instantly?

Tags: excel, vba, module, global-variables

I am refactoring an Excel spreadsheet that includes several modules. In the ThisWorkbook object one finds the following code:

```
Option Explicit
set ws = ActiveSheet
```

During execution of the code, the thread enters one of the modules. In this module we find the object declaration:

```
Global ws as Worksheet
```

I know that global variables can be used in all modules. Does this mean that the function declaration takes place *after* the function definition? Or are all global variables in all modules in the application declared before running any code?

Comment: Side note... if you're refactoring, global variables like this should be eliminated IMO (and others') ... see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772922/9245853).

Answer (score 3):

Declarations aren't executable code, whether they're global, module, or locally scoped (`Dim` statements aren't executable; `Dim...As New` aren't executable either). So, yes, they're declared "instantly". If the module is loaded (i.e. if any of its members are used in any execution path down your code's entry point), then everything it defines, is defined.

Note, the `Global` keyword is obsolete/useless: a `Global` variable is in no way any different than any other `Public` variable.

As @BigBen mentioned in comments, a global-scope `ws As Worksheet` object looks very very much like the type of global state variable you would want to eliminate in a project you're refactoring.